# Is there a way to prevent a python 3 script from being called in python 2?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to turn in an assignment, and I'm extremely concerned that, since the single TA has many projects to run, it will be called using `python`, which will call python 2.7, when the program is written for `python3.2` and should be called that way. This would result in a syntax error, and I would loose points. I know when working on side projects, this happens a lot, and if the TA encountered this I don't think he would follow up.

I'm going to submit a `readme`, but I was wondering if there was a way to catch this in my code without a lot of fuss, and print a statement that said to rerun the project as `python3.2 project.py`. I could to a `try: print "Rerun project…" except:pass`, but is there a better way?

Comment: If your class is using python, and hasn't specified if they're using Python 2 or Python 3, then you have bigger problems than that.

Comment: @aruisdante My project can be written in whatever I'd like, and I chose `python`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do:

```
import sys
print(sys.version_info)
```

As of Python 2.7 you can also use:

```
print(sys.version_info.major, sys.version_info.minor, sys.version_info.micro)
```

You can use the value of `sys.version_info` to print a warning when the Python version currently running isn't as desired.

You can also use:

```
import platform
print(platform.python_version())
```

Comment: although since the OP wants to run using Py3, you should probably use `print()`

Comment: How would I stop it from running once started though?

Comment: @JFA: you can call `sys.exit(0)` to exit the execution of the Python code.

Comment: Or throw an exception with a descriptive error message.

Comment: One other thing the OP will have to avoid is any Python-3 specific syntax, like `x, *y = range(3)`, for example.  That will cause a `SyntaxError` before any code is even executed.

Comment: or call `sys.exit('Please run this program with Python 3.2')` to exit and explain why, all at once.

Comment: I see, I can call sys.version_info.major and if it's not 3 throw an exception or exit.

Comment: My python 2 version returns a SyntaxError for a syntax specific to Python 3, even tough the file starts by checking the python version

Answer (score 7):

How about starting the program like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import sys

if sys.version_info < (3,0,0):
    print(__file__ + ' requires Python 3, while Python ' + str(sys.version[0] + ' was detected. Terminating. '))
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: This is a great suggestion. I figured there was a clean, not hacky way of doing this natively.

Answer (score 5):

This is actually a harder problem to implement well that you might at first think.

Suppose you have the following code:

```
import platform
import sys

if platform.python_version().startswith('2'):
    # This NEVER will be executed no matter the version of Python
    # because of the two syntax errors below...
    sys.stdout.write("You're using python 2.x! Python 3.2+ required!!!")
    sys.exit()     
else:
    # big program or def main(): and calling main() .. whatever
    # later in that file/module:
    x, *y=(1,2,3)      # syntax error on Python 2...
    # or
    print 'test'       # syntax error on Python 3...
```

One of the two syntax errors under the `else` clause is generated BEFORE the `if` is actually executed no matter the version of Python used to run it. Therefore, the program will not gracefully exit as you might expect; it will fail with a syntax error no matter what.

The workaround is to put your actual program in an external file/module and wrap in a `try/except` this way:

```
try:
    import Py3program    # make sure it has syntax guaranteed to fail on 
                         # Python 2 like    x, *y=1,2,3
except SyntaxError:
    sys.stdout.write(error message)
    sys.exit()

# rest of the Python 3 program...
```

If your TA will execute the file with a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29), that would be a better approach still. Perhaps ask the TA how he will run your script?

Comment: They just compile and run them from the command prompt. the concern is that he would run `python script` and see a bunch of errors when really he was calling the wrong interpreter.

Comment: This except does not seem to work, I still get the SyntaxError: invalid syntax error despite using it on python2.7.16